# VS Code acquireVsCodeApi(); not detected in web view

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, svelte, vscode-extensions

I am trying to design a VS Code extension using Typescript and Svelte. I want the extension to display a message when a button in the web view is clicked. For this, I have written the following Sidebar.svelte code:

```
<script lang="ts">
    let text='';
</script>

<style>
    .main-container{
        height: 98vh;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .output-container{
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-radius: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .input-container{
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
    input{
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
</style>

<div class="main-container">
    <div class="output-container">
        Your text will appear here:
      {text}
    </div>
  
    <div class="input-container">
      <input bind:value={text} placeholder="Enter text" />
      <button on:click={()=>{
        tsvscode.postMessage({type:"onInfo",value:"ok"});
      }}>Show info</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is SidebarProvider.ts that loads the webview and should be receiving the message on button click:

```
import * as vscode from "vscode";
import { getNonce } from "./getNonce";
import { apiUrl } from "./constants";

export class SidebarProvider implements vscode.WebviewViewProvider {
  _view?: vscode.WebviewView;
  _doc?: vscode.TextDocument;

  constructor(private readonly _extensionUri: vscode.Uri) {}

  public resolveWebviewView(webviewView: vscode.WebviewView) {
    this._view = webviewView;

    webviewView.webview.options = {
      // Allow scripts in the webview
      enableScripts: true,

      localResourceRoots: [this._extensionUri],
    };

    webviewView.webview.html = this._getHtmlForWebview(webviewView.webview);

    webviewView.webview.onDidReceiveMessage(async (data) => {
      switch (data.type) {
        
        case "onInfo": {
          if (!data.value) {
            return;
          }
          vscode.window.showInformationMessage(data.value);
          break;
        }
        case "onError": {
          if (!data.value) {
            return;
          }
          vscode.window.showErrorMessage(data.value);
          break;
        }
      }
    });
  }

  public revive(panel: vscode.WebviewView) {
    this._view = panel;
  }

  private _getHtmlForWebview(webview: vscode.Webview) {
    const styleResetUri = webview.asWebviewUri(
      vscode.Uri.joinPath(this._extensionUri, "media", "reset.css")
    );
    const scriptUri = webview.asWebviewUri(
      vscode.Uri.joinPath(this._extensionUri, "out", "compiled/sidebar.js")
    );
    const styleMainUri = webview.asWebviewUri(
      vscode.Uri.joinPath(this._extensionUri, "out", "compiled/bundle.css")
    );
    const styleVSCodeUri = webview.asWebviewUri(
      vscode.Uri.joinPath(this._extensionUri, "media", "vscode.css")
    );

    // Use a nonce to only allow a specific script to be run.
    const nonce = getNonce();

    return `<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
                <head>
                    <meta charset="UTF-8">
                    <!--
                        Use a content security policy to only allow loading images from https or from our extension directory,
                        and only allow scripts that have a specific nonce.
                    -->
                    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src https: data:; style-src 'unsafe-inline' ${webview.cspSource}; script-src 'nonce-${nonce}';">
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                    <link href="${styleResetUri}" rel="stylesheet">
                    <link href="${styleVSCodeUri}" rel="stylesheet">
                    <link href="${styleMainUri}" rel="stylesheet">
                    <script nonce ="${getNonce}"> const tsvscode = acquireVsCodeApi(); </script>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <script nonce="${nonce}" src="${scriptUri}"></script>
                </body>
            </html>`;
  }
}
```

To make tsvscode available to the svelte file, I made a globals.d.ts file with the following declaration:

```
import * as _vscode from "vscode";

declare global {
    const tsvscode:{
        postMessage: ({type: string, value:any})=>void;
    };
}
```

But, I am getting the following error on the webview developer tools console on running this:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: tsvscode is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.click_handler (sidebar.js:619:4)
click_handler @ sidebar.js:619
```

and this warning on the console:

```
Plugin svelte: 'tsvscode' is not defined
[0] webviews/components/Sidebar.svelte
[0] 35:       <input bind:value={text} placeholder="Enter text" />
[0] 36:       <button on:click={()=>{
[0] 37:         tsvscode.postMessage({type:"onInfo",value:"ok"});
[0]             ^
[0] 38:       }}>Show info</button>
[0] 39:     </div>
```

Can you please tell me what could be causing this error and how to resolve it?